# Regular expression to check if a String is a positive natural number

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a string is a positive natural number but I don't want to use `Integer.parseInt()` because the user may enter a number larger than an int.  Instead I would prefer to use a regex to return false if a numeric String contains all "0" characters.

```
if(val.matches("[0-9]+")){
    // We know that it will be a number, but what if it is "000"?
    // what should I change to make sure 
    // "At Least 1 character in the String is from 1-9"
}
```

Note: the string must contain only `0`-`9` and it must not contain all `0`s; in other words it must have at least 1 character in `[1-9]`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "positive number"?  Is `2.5` a positive number?  What about `π`?

Comment: updated--> positive natural number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd be better off using [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) if you're trying to work with an arbitrarily large integer, however the following pattern should match a series of digits containing at least one non-zero character.

```
\d*[1-9]\d*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/rg9jF3AETqaCMAj8)

Debugex's unit tests seem a little buggy, but you can play with the pattern there.  It's simple enough that it should be reasonably cross-language compatible, but in Java you'd need to escape it.

```
Pattern positiveNumber = Pattern.compile("\\d*[1-9]\\d*");
```

---

Note the above (intentionally) matches strings we wouldn't normally consider "positive natural numbers", as a valid string can start with one or more `0`s, e.g. `000123`.  If you don't want to match such strings, you can simplify the pattern further.

```
[1-9]\d*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ZEmlyzwjNlq1mnX-)

```
Pattern exactPositiveNumber = Pattern.compile("[1-9]\\d*");
```

Comment: @AlexandreSantos This regex rejects "0" so it works.

Comment: it does work for 0, great simple solution, thax u very muxh Dimo

Comment: This matches "092383". Should that be allowed? If that's allowed, shouldn't "+92383" be allowed as well? How about `\+?\d*[1-9]\d*`?

Comment: I don't want + in the string

Comment: Admittedly the question's requirements are vague (which is why I really suggest using `BigInteger`), but I infer from "*if a String contain[s] all '0' char then return false*" that a string like `092383` should match.  We can expand the pattern if OP clarifies the requirements.

Comment: It's "Positive natural number"

Comment: To be fair, `092383` is not normally consider a valid representation of a natural number.

Comment: @dimo414, 092383 is absolutely a natural number.  It's just not written in the standard way.

Comment: Hi Dino, I just updated my question, is it clear enough for you? does ur solution meet my requirement?

Comment: @DavidWallace fair enough, clarified my comment.

Comment: @Tum yes, either of the patterns I posted will match the strings you're describing, depending on how restrictive you're trying to be.

Comment: thax u very much for ur solution

Comment: @dimo414 If you only want (positive) natural numbers and without dost, comma or anything then `^[1-9]+$` is a better way to do it.

Comment: @RemziCavdar that doesn't match `10`....

Comment: @dimo414 Oops, you're right. Could you help me with this one?

Comment: Use `[1-9]\d*`, like I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @dimo414 Doesn't work for me and I have tested it on https://regex101.com

Comment: I'd suggest posting a new question; saying "doesn't work for me" with no other details on an eight year old question is not a good way to get help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249005/discussion-between-remzi-cavdar-and-dimo414).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match positive natural numbers, written in the standard way, without a leading zero, the regular expression you want is

```
[1-9]\d*
```

which matches any string of characters consisting only of digits, where the first digit is not zero.  Don't forget to double the backslash (`"[1-9]\\d*"`) if you write it as a Java String literal.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following regex for only positive natural numbers:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

This will will check if a number starts with 1 to 9 (so there can't be any zero's in the beginning) and there rest of the numbers need to be numbers from 0 to 9. You can test it at https://regex101.com