# How to interpret string as a negative number or zero and throw IAE accordingly?

Tags: java, guava, preconditions

I have a method in which I am accepting a String and that can be number as a string or a normal string.

```
public Builder setClientId(String clientId) {
    checkNotNull(clientId, "clientId cannot be null");
    checkArgument(clientId.length() > 0, "clientId can't be an empty string");
    this.clientId = clientId;
    return this;
}
```

Now I want to add a check let's say if anyone is passing `clientId` as negative number `"-12345"` or zero `"0"`, then I want to interpret this and throw `IllegalArgumentException` with message as `"clientid must not be negative or zero as a number"` or may be some other good message. How can I do this using guava Preconditions if possible?

As per suggestion I am using below code:

```
public Builder setClientId(String clientId) {
    checkNotNull(clientId, "clientId cannot be null");
    checkArgument(clientId.length() > 0, "clientId can't be an empty string");
    checkArgument(!clientid.matches("-\\d+|0"), "clientid must not be negative or zero");
    this.clientId = clientId;
    return this;
}
```

Is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: ```if (clientId.matches("-\\d+|0") throw new IllegalArgumentException("clientid must not be negative or zero as a number");```

Comment: Why can't you parse it and check either that it is either not a number or not a negative number?

Comment: So, `-10` should be rejected, but `-1O` should be accepted? (zero digit vs. letter oh)

Comment: @MiserableVariable I was trying to see whether there is a better way in one line by which we can do this without writing big if else try catch block to do this.

Comment: You could use the regular expression @saka1029 gave but actual parsing  seems more readable to me

Comment: @MiserableVariable I see another SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645577/regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-positive-natural-number) but regex is slightly different. Which one should I use?

Comment: You can use Strings.isNullOrEmpty() for null empty check: <http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty(java.lang.String)>

Comment: How would you  check the non-number part? Overall nunber parsing  seems best to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way of doing this is as follows:

```
 public Builder setClientId(String clientId) {
    final Integer id = Ints.tryParse(clientId);
    checkArgument(id != null && id.intValue() > 0,
      "clientId must be a positive number, found: '%s'.", clientId);
    this.clientId = clientId;
    return this;
  }
```

When calling this method, this gives:

```
.setClientId("+-2"); 
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: clientId must be a positive number, found: '+-2'.

.setClientId("-1"); 
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: clientId must be a positive number, found: '-1'.

.setClientId(null); 
// java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This code uses [`Ints.tryParse`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse(java.lang.String)). From the JavaDoc:

> **Returns:**
>
> the integer value represented by `string`, or `null` if `string` has a length of zero or cannot be parsed as an integer value

Also, it throws a `NullPointerException` when a `null` is received.

---

**Edit:** however, if any other string is allowed, the code changes to:

```
public Builder setClientId(String clientId) {
    checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(clientId),
      "clientId may not be null or an empty string, found '%s'.", clientId);
    final Integer id = Ints.tryParse(clientId);
    if (id != null) {
      checkArgument(id.intValue() > 0,
        "clientId must be a positive number, found: '%s'.", clientId);
    }
    this.clientId = clientId;
    return this;
  }
```

This code will accept all strings that are either a strictly positive integer OR non-null and non-empty.

Comment: Also my requirement is if clientId is a proper string, then I want to allow that as well. So basically requirement is - `clientId` can be a number and if it is then it should be positive number greater than zero and `clientId` can be normal string as well.

Comment: I added a second version that allows normal strings as well.

Comment: Thanks looks good. Instead of using Integer for id, is there any long as well like `Longs.tryParse` because clientId can be Long instead of Integer.

Comment: Yes, Longs.tryParse and Doubles.tryParse exist so you can use the one you like.

Comment: I don't see for Longs. I get this error `The method tryParse(String) is undefined for the type Longs`

Comment: Are you using Guava 14 or later? This is the [JavaDoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Longs.html#tryParse(java.lang.String)).